# Ghostscript find out more debugging information

Tags: ghostscript

I am creating a pdf file using ghostscript 9.15. I have been using ghostscript for about 5 years and haven’t encountered any serious issues till this week.

Essentially I am running the query below….

```
“c://distiller/exes/gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE="pdfwrite"   -dNOPAUSE  -dBATCH -dNOSAFER  -dQUIET  -sFONTPATH="C:/Windows/Fonts" -sOUTPUTFILE="C:\distiller\test.pdf" "C:\ExactDistiller \example.ps"
```

and I get the error below

> Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: No such file or
>   directory Current file position is 197197 GPL Ghostscript 9.15:
>   Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

I am getting the error “No such file or directory” but I have checked every file path and checked every font is installed and all seems fine but still no luck. I just want to know is there a way of finding out what file / directory is causing the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Well the first thing I would do is not set `-dQUIET`, turning off information isn't a good way to debug a problem. Not setting `-dBATCH` and `-dNOPAUSE` might be helpful too as it might show you more of what is going on. Note that `-dNOSAFER` is in fact the default, you don't need to set that unless you have previously set your environment to include `-dSAFER`

In short, when trying to debug the problem, simplify it as far as possible, don't set any switches unless you know you need them, or they contribute to the problem.

You could then paste the stdout transcript which might shed some illumination.

Secondly, your directory appears to contain a trailing space before the separator `"c:\ExactDistiller \example.ps"`, is that correct ? A 'No such file or directory' error will be thrown (without a PostScript error) if you get the input filename incorrect.

If there is a PostScript error revealed when you stop issuing `-dQUIET` then you can paste it in your original question (by editing it) and I'll take a look. It may be necessary to see your example.ps file, depending on what that reveals.